# Static Variable in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, static-variables

Please review following code, i am not understanding where i am WRONG.
I need to know in Broadcastreciever whether APPLICATION IS AT FOREGROUND or in BACKGROUND. But in Recevier it always Returning FALSE. **Why the value of static variable in BASEAPPLICATION lost?? Why its Showing FALSE always**

```
public class Main extends Activity  {
        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
                  super.onResume();
                  BaseApplication.activityResumed();
                  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                  Intent intent = new Intent(context, Recevier.class);
                  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, intentCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                  am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentMilliSeconds() + 2000, pi);
        }
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            BaseApplication.activityPaused();
            }
```

**BROADCAST RECIEVER**

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(BaseApplication.isActivityVisible()){
         // Application is Running

        }
       else{
          // Applicaiton is not Running
//**ALWAYS GIVING FALSE**
            }
    }
```

**BASE APPLICATION **

```
public class BaseApplication {
    public static boolean isActivityVisible() {

        return activityVisible;
      }  

      public static void activityResumed() {
        activityVisible = true;

      }

      public static void activityPaused() {
        activityVisible = false;

      }

      private static boolean activityVisible;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had better to check the top activity of activity stack.

```
public boolean isActivityVisible(Context context) {
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.
    getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    String className = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
    return Main.class.getName().equals(className);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the application is not aware of your BaseApplication class.

You should:

1. Your base application class should extend [Application object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)
2. Your manifest should point out in the `application` tag the attribute `name` and point to you application object

P.S. the `BaseApplication.activityPaused();` should go into `onPause` and not `onStop`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the state of "activityVisible" you need save it in SharedPreferences.

Comment: Yes I did same, but Whats the reason behind that static variable.